# Using an image as a background attribute in android layouts causes huge lag. How to fix?

Tags: android, image, view, background, lag

So I am building a rather complicated budget management application. I am still struggling with this problem though. I have seen apps like Yahoo!Weather utilizing huge high-resolution images as their activity backgrounds and their app runs smoothly. However when I assign an image file as an android:background to a View this makes the application lag out like nothing else. What is the way to work around this? (I assume there is one.)

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Are you using one huge high resolution image in `drawable` folder ?

Comment: nope, not a huge high resolution image in my case, was just giving an example. I have the original (1080x1920) and I have scaled it down several times for the xxhdpi, xhdpi, hdpi and mdpi screens.

Comment: try using `AsyncTask` [what is AsyncTask?](http://programmerguru.com/android-tutorial/what-is-asynctask-in-android/) and [example of AsyncTask](http://programmerguru.com/android-tutorial/android-asynctask-example/)

Comment: for loading the background?

Comment: @SagarPilkhwal, he is not loading from server... So no need of `AsyncTask`

Comment: i think so too, the image is already available in the app

Comment: Try crunching the png's, [Check this](http://developer.sonymobile.com/2012/01/31/tips-for-reducing-apk-file-size/)

Comment: if you want to get high resolution image, the last resort will be Slicing the images into smaller pieces and making appropriate `ImageView` for them, But again its a last resort.

Comment: android would still need to load all the information and render it as an android:background attribute, even divided in smaller parts. I don't think that would work.

Comment: have you tried it on a actual device? or just on android emulator?

Comment: On several of them, yes.